# How do I deploy a Xamarin (Android) APK to my phone in Debug Mode

Tags: xamarin, deploying

In Visual Studio when I want to run my project, my only choice now is the Android_Accelerated_X86_Oreo emulator. I would like to deploy to my cell phone. I have been able to do that but suddenly I cannot. I have Dev Options enabled and the USB connection is in File Transfer mode. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try deleting old version of the app from the phone. And restart the xamarin studio. delete the bin folder after restarting the studio and clean the solution before deploying again. Many tmes it worked for me.

Comment: did not work. But recently (yesterday) it worked OK. Just frustrating. I'm used to a unified environment (VS) and this seems a bit...haphazard.

Comment: Have you enabled usb debbuging on your phone? If yes, close vs and open it again with phone connected in your computer. Sometimes vs does not recognize device instantly. Try also removing/adding phone cable.

Comment: yes, yes, and yes. I spend almost more time trying to get VS/Xamarin to recognize the phone than I do coding. I do not understand where or on what basis VS decides to output to the emulated android phone. What is it looking for? Of course I could ask Microsoft (just joking). I've unplugged and plugged in the phone. I am using a USB port on the computer (not on a hub). I have restarted VS. What's left? Prayer?

Comment: I also deleted the bin and obj folders and restarted VS. Same.

Comment: Is it working now or not?

Comment: No, it's not. No idea why.